# Close then open tag in loop

Tags: xslt

Looking at an old xslt (that as far as I know was working, written by someone else ages ago) where a tag is started before a loop and then closed and reopened inside the loop and finally closed after the loop is done.  So all tags would end up matching.  But when I try to look at it in VS 2013, I get a start tag does not match end tag error.

It's possible this never did work...

Anyway the structure looks like..

```
<div>
   Blah
   <xsl:for-each>
       different blah
       <xsl:if>
</div>
<div>
       Yet more blah
       </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </div>
```

Is there a quick way to get this to work, without trying to restructure everything to be in the same loop?

Comment: That cannot work because the existing XML has to be valid. That's not valid XML, period.

Comment: It's possible only if you output the interim tags as (escaped) text, with disable-output-escaping turned on.

Comment: Not that it works, but this sort of 'pattern' is often attempted when you have consecutive elements in the XML that you want to split into groups; for example to put groups of 3 elements in a DIV. There is another approach that could be taken, but to give a precise answer it would help if you showed the input XML, a bit more of the XSLT (i.e the `select` attributes of the `for-each` and `if`), and the expected output (if you can work it out!) Thanks!

Comment: @michael.hor257k: you should make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a quick way to get this to work, without trying to
>   restructure everything to be in the same loop?

It's possible, if you output the intervening tags as text, with `disable-output-escaping` turned on - for example:

```
...
<div>
    <!--  something -->
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <!--  something -->
        <xsl:if test="@divide='yes'">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/div>&#10;&lt;div></xsl:text>
            <!--  something -->
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</div>
...
```

This is of course a horrible hack and you should take the first opportunity to replace it with some decent code.

Comment: Thanks, and agreed on all counts.  I was hoping that my limited knowledge was leading me to either spend a lot of time on something I can't spend a lot of time on (ie leave it broken) or using something that everyone seems to be calling a terrible hack, when there was a perfectly acceptable solution just waiting to be found.  Now that I have confirmation that it is either rewrite or hack, I can move forward.

Comment: @jmoreno Keep in mind that we don't know what is being processed here and what is the condition under which a "split" should occur. Perhaps the rewrite is trivial?